# How to make this code more efficient in R?

Tags: r, performance, dataframe, matrix

I know this is a stupid question, but I'm kinda frustrated with my code because it takes so much time. Jere is one part of my code. 
basically I have a matrix called "distance"...

```
   a  b  c  
1  2  5  7
2  6  8  4
3  9  2  3
```

and then lets say I have a column in a data frame, contains of {a,b,c}

```
c1  c2  c3
c  ...  ...
a
a  just another column
b
c ... ...
```

so I want to do a match, I wanna make another matrix with ncol=nrow(distance), and nrow=nrow(c1). where replace the factor value with their distance value. Here's an example of the first column of matrix that I'm going to make

```
a will replaced by 2 
b will replaced by 5
c will replaced by 7
```

and for the second column, i will take row number 2 from distance matrix, and so on... so the result will be like this

```
m1  m2  m3
7   4   3
2   6   9
2   6   9
5   8   2
7   4   3
```

That is just an easy example, and I'm running this code, but when it deals with large iterations, it's kinda stressful for me.

```
for(l in 1:ncol(d.cat)){
  get.unique = sort(unique(d.cat[, l]))
  for(j in 1:nrow(d.cat)){
    value = as.character(d.cat[j, l])
    index = which(get.unique == value)
    d2[j,l] = (d[[l]][i, index])
  }
}
```

d.cat is categorical data. And d[[...]] is the list of matrix distance for every column in d.cat.

Comment: I removed the `[rcpp]` tag as this has nothing to do with Rcpp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some data

```
set.seed(123)
d = matrix(1:9, 3, dimnames=list(NULL, letters[1:3]))
df = data.frame(c1 = sample(letters[1:3], 10, TRUE), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

and a solution

```
t(d[, match(df$c1, colnames(d))])
```

For example

```
> d
     a b c
[1,] 1 4 7
[2,] 2 5 8
[3,] 3 6 9
> df$c1
 [1] "a" "c" "b" "c" "c" "a" "b" "c" "b" "b"
> t(d[,match(df$c1, colnames(d))])
  [,1] [,2] [,3]
a    1    2    3
c    7    8    9
b    4    5    6
c    7    8    9
c    7    8    9
a    1    2    3
b    4    5    6
c    7    8    9
b    4    5    6
b    4    5    6
```

Comment: with your way make my code running in 1.7 minutes before, and now just 9 seconds... thank u so much

Answer (score 2):

Try to store the indices and do the updating in one go. Lets say your distance matrix is dmat and data frame is df and you want to create a matrix named newmat

```
a.ind = which(df$c1=="a")
b.ind = which(df$c1=="b")
c.ind = which(df$c1=="c")
newmat = matrix(0,nrow=length(df$c1),ncol=3)
newmat[a.ind,] = dmat[,1]
newmat[b.ind,] = dmat[,2]
newmat[c.ind,] = dmat[,3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your data

```
mat <- matrix(c(2,6,9,5,8,2,7,4,3), nrow=3)
rownames(mat) <- 1:3
colnames(mat) <- letters[1:3]

library(dplyr)
set.seed(1)
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(letters[1:3], 12, replace=TRUE), nrow=4)) %>%
        setNames(paste0("c", 1:3))

  # c1 c2 c3
# 1  a  a  b
# 2  b  c  a
# 3  b  c  a
# 4  c  b  a
```

Using `purrr::map2_df`, iterate through columns of `df` and columns of `tmat`

```
library(purrr)
tmat <- t(mat)
map2_df(df, seq_len(ncol(tmat)), ~tmat[,.y][.x])

# # A tibble: 4 x 3
     # c1    c2    c3
  # <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1    2.    6.    2.
# 2    5.    4.    9.
# 3    5.    4.    9.
# 4    7.    8.    9.
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt using the tidyverse :

```
library(tidyverse)

# Lets create some example
distance <- data_frame(a = sample(1:10, 1000, T), b = sample(1:10, 1000, T), c = sample(1:10, 1000, T))
c1 <- data_frame(c1 = sample(letters[1:3], 1000, T), c2 = sample(letters[1:3], 1000, T))

# First rearrange a little bit your data to make it more tidy
distance2 <- distance %>% 
  mutate(i = seq_len(n())) %>% 
  gather(col, value, -i)
c2 <- c1 %>% 
  mutate(i = seq_len(n()) %>%
  gather(col, value, -i)

# Now just join the data and spread it again
c12 %>% 
  left_join(distance2, by = c("i", "value" = "col")) %>% 
  select(i, col, value.y) %>% 
  spread(col, value.y)
```